# How to publish Facebook custom graph stories?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Though I successfully published the action as test user from development mode of Android App, Facebook is still showing the below message when I am trying to submit this action for review.

1. [Image of Shared in Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5DAJ.png)
2. [Image of Alert while submitting App action for review to Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcT7n.png)

This is the code sample for share the action.

```
 ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "game")
            .putString("og:title", "Janoki Tiger English Competition!")
            .putString("og:description", "I got " + ans + " score in Janoki Tiger English Competition! I'm ranked " + rank + "th out of " + participants + " participants!")
                    //give a image url here
            .putString("og:image", "")
            .putString("og:url", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=venturas.bd.janoki")
            .putString("fb:app_id","")

            .build();


    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("venturas-bd-janoki:game")
            .putObject("game", object)
            .build();

    // Create the content
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("game")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
ShareDialog.show(this, content);
```

Comment: Is there code we could help you fix?

Comment: Yes i am updating the question with code.

Comment: @J.Chomel i update my question with code

Comment: Thanks! This will be much easier to answer.